# Configuration ID of a Test ID in HP Quality Center

Tags: vba, hp-quality-center

I was writing VB Script to retrieve the config ID of a test ID. I get the test ID, Name, Status with following code:

```
Dim TSTestFact = tsObject.TSTestFactory
Dim TestSetTestsList = TSTestFact.NewList("")

For Each tsInstance In TestSetTestsList
            Dim tid As String = tsInstance.ID
            Dim testqcID As String = tsInstance.TestID
            Dim testname As String = tsInstance.Name
            Dim statusOfTest As String = tsInstance.Status
Next
```

This works fine and I am happy. But, my problem is that I can not get the information about config ID of a test ID. Any ideas or suggestions regarding how to get the test configuration ID or similar information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a TestConfig object with `tsInstance.TestConfiguration`. Then you can get the ID of this object. Untested code:

```
Dim testConfiguration As TestConfig = tsInstance.TestConfiguration
Dim testConfigID As String = testConfiguration.ID
```

It seems there is also another way to get the TestConfiguration object: Via the `TDConnection.TestConfigFactory`. The TestConfigFactory allows you to apply filters the same way as other factory-objects.

Comment: I tested the code and works perfectly fine. I used the first way to get a TestConfig object with tsInstance.TestConfiguration  Thank you so much!!